# Why integration by parts "doesn't work" here?

Tags: integration

Let $$I=\int \frac{1}{x\ln(x)} dx $$. We know that $I=\ln|\ln|x|| + C $ But if we integrate by parts such that $u=\dfrac{1}{\ln(x)}$ & $dv=\dfrac{dx}{x}$ and $du=-\dfrac{dx}{x\ln(x)^2} ,\; v=\ln|x|$
We end up with $$I=\frac{\ln|x|}{\ln(x)}+\int \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx$$, therefore $$0=1$$?
I assume it has something to do with the absolute values.

Comment: An antiderivative is not a single function, but rather a family of functions which differ by constants of integration. As a consequence, we have "equality" like $$ \int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\mathsf{C}$$ for any constant $\mathsf{C}$. Since $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is not a single value (and thus the above identity holds in the sense of an equality of sets), you cannot cancel out $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, just like we cannot cancel out $\mathbb{R}$ from both sides of the equality $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}+2020$ to deduce $0\stackrel{?}=2020$.

Comment: What about an integration constant?

Comment: @SangchulLee You're right. Totally forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the sum in your second method is not right. It should be $$\int\frac1x\frac{\log|x|\mathrm dx}{(\log x)^2},$$ since the derivative of $1/\log x$ is $$-\frac{1/x}{(\log x)^2}.$$